# basic_string::_M_construct null not valid issue

Tags: c++

I've encountered a problem whilst making a blackjack game and not quite sure how to resolve it myself. The error reads **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid**. The problem seems to arise from the final call to the calculateScores() method, but not sure why the problem arises.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

bool someoneWon = false;
const char* cards[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
string names[] = {"Dealer", "Ethan", "Brian", "Taha"};
int randNum1, randNum2;
int dealerScore, ethanScore, brianScore, tahaScore, playerScore = 0;

void calculateScores(int num1, int num2, string iName) {
    //Add scores
    if (iName == names[0]) dealerScore += num1 += num2;
    else if (iName == names[1]) ethanScore += num1 += num2;
    else if (iName == names[2]) brianScore += num1 += num2;
    else if (iName == names[3]) tahaScore += num1 += num2;
    else if (iName == names[4]) playerScore += num1 += num2;
    //Checks for winner
    if (dealerScore > 20) {
        cout << "Dealer has won";
        someoneWon = true;
    } else if (ethanScore > 20) {
        cout << "Ethan has won";
        someoneWon = true;
    } else if (brianScore > 20) {
        cout << "Brian has won";
        someoneWon = true;
    } else if (tahaScore > 20) {
        cout << "Taha has won";
        someoneWon = true;
    } else if (playerScore > 20) {
        cout << "You won";
        someoneWon = true;
    }
}

void startGame() {
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        randNum1 = rand() % 13;
        randNum2 = rand() % 13;
        //dealer
        if (i == 0) {
            cout << "Dealer has " << cards[randNum1] << " and another hidden card." << endl;
            calculateScores(randNum1, randNum2, names[i]);
        //AI players
        } else if (i < 4) {
            cout << names[i] << " has a " << cards[randNum1] << " and a " << cards[randNum2] << endl;
            calculateScores(randNum1, randNum2, names[i]);
        //Actual player
        } else {
            cout << "You have a " << cards[randNum1] << " and a " << cards[randNum2] << endl;
            calculateScores(randNum1, randNum2, names[i]);
            char userOption; cout << "Would you like to hit or stand? (h/s): "; cin >> userOption;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    system("cls");
    startGame();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `names` is an array of four strings, `names[4]` is accessing this array out of bounds. Perhaps you forgot to put `, "Player"` at the end (after `, "Taha"`)?

Answer (score 0):

**TL DR**

```
string names[] = {"Dealer", "Ethan", "Brian", "Taha" }; // Problem

string names[] = {"Dealer", "Ethan", "Brian", "Taha", "foo" }; // Fix
```

---

*Long answer*

in the for loop `for (int i=0; i<5; i++)` if `i == 4` it gets into `else`

```
} else {
            cout << "You have a " << cards[randNum1] << " and a " << cards[randNum2] << endl;
            calculateScores(randNum1, randNum2, names[i]);
            char userOption; cout << "Would you like to hit or stand? (h/s): "; cin >> userOption;
        }
```

in this else this below statement tries to access `names[i]` here `i` is 4  `calculateScores(randNum1, randNum2, names[i]);`
and `names` defined as

```
string names[] = {"Dealer", "Ethan", "Brian", "Taha"};
```

making access to `names[4]` illegal, resulting in failure